# Efficient joining the most recent record from another table in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am comming to ASP .NET Core from PHP w/ MySQL.

---

**The problem:**

For the illustration, suppose the following two tables:
`T: {ID, Description, FK}` and `States: {ID, ID_T, Time, State}`. There is 1:n relationship between them (`ID_T` references `T.ID`).

I need all the records from `T` with some specific value of `FK` (lets say `1`) along with the related newest record in `States` (if any).

---

In terms of SQL it can be written as:

```sql
SELECT T.ID, T.Description, COALESCE(s.State, 0) AS 'State' FROM T
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID_T, MAX(Time) AS 'Time'
    FROM States
    GROUP BY ID_T
) AS sub ON T.ID = sub.ID_T
LEFT JOIN States AS s ON T.ID = s.ID_T AND sub.Time = s.Time
WHERE FK = 1
```

I am struggling to write an efficient equivalent query in LINQ (or the fluent API). The best working solution I've got so far is:

```cs
from t in _context.T
where t.FK == 1
join s in _context.States on t.ID equals o.ID_T into _s
from s in _s.DefaultIfEmpty()
let x = new
{
    id = t.ID,
    time = s == null ? null : (DateTime?)s.Time,
    state = s == null ? false : s.State
}
group x by x.id into x
select x.OrderByDescending(g => g.time).First();
```

When I check the resulting SQL query in the output window when executed it is just like:

```sql
SELECT [t].[ID], [t].[Description], [t].[FK], [s].[ID], [s].[ID_T], [s].[Time], [s].[State]
FROM [T] AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [States] AS [s] ON [T].[ID] = [s].[ID_T]
WHERE [t].[FK] = 1
ORDER BY [t].[ID]
```

Not only it selects more columns than I need (in the real scheme there are more of them). **There is no grouping in the query** so I suppose it selects everything from the DB (and `States` is going to be huge) and the grouping/filtering is happening outside the DB.

---

**The questions:**

What would you do?

- Is there an efficient query in LINQ / Fluent API?
- If not, what workarounds can be used?

  - Raw SQL ruins the concept of abstracting from a specific DB technology and its use is very clunky in current Entity Framework Core *(but maybe its the best solution)*.
  - To me, this looks like a good example for using a database view - again, not really supported by Entity Framework Core *(but maybe its the best solution)*.

Comment: "Efficiency" and "Entity Framework" don't go together.

Comment: In EF Core group by is done in memory. EF Core orders results on grouping key to allow streaming and efficient group by no group by is sent to Server. Tracking issue https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2341

Comment: @Smit: Thank you. I already found this article: https://jonhilton.net/2016/11/09/is-entity-framework-core-production-ready/

I'll try to Switch to EF6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Reading [this article](https://jonhilton.net/2016/11/09/is-entity-framework-core-production-ready/) (almost a year old now), Smit's comment to the original question and other sources, it seems that **EF Core is not really production ready yet**. It is not able to translate grouping to SQL and therefore it is performed on the client side, which may be (and in my case would be) a serious problem. It corresponds to the observed behavior (the generated SQL query does no grouping and selects everything in all groups). Trying the LINQ queries out in Linqpad it always translates to a single SQL query.

**I have downgraded to EF6** following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6). It required some changes in my model's code and some queries. After changing `.First()` to `.FirstOrDefault()` in my original LINQ query it works fine and translates to a single SQL query selecting only the needed columns. The generated query is much more complex than it is needed, though.

Using a query from NetMage's answer (after small fixes), it results in a SQL query almost identical to my own original SQL query (there's only a more complex construct than `COALESCE`).

```
var latestState = from s in _context.States
                  group s by s.ID_T into sg
                  select new { ID = sg.Key, Time = sg.Time.Max() };

var ans = from t in _context.T
          where t.FK == 1
          join sub in latestState on t.ID equals sub.ID into subj
          from sub in subj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          join s in _context.States
              on new { ID_T = t.ID, sub.Time } equals new { s.ID_T, s.Time }
              into sj
          from s in sj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new { t.ID, t.Description, State = (s == null ? false : s.State) };
```

In LINQ it's not as elegant as my original SQL query but semantically it's the same and it does more or less the same thing on the DB side.

In EF6 it is also much more convenient to use arbitrary raw SQL queries and AFAIK also the database views.

**The biggest downside of this approach is that full .NET framework has to be targeted, EF6 is not compatible with .NET Core.**

Comment: I wasn't sure of the type of `State`, but apparently you can use `??` in a LINQ query and have it translate to SQL but maybe it can apply to a table being null since unfortunately `?.` isn't translated yet. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @NetMage: Thank you! will try that on Monday and eventually update my answer

Comment: Whenever I'm concerned about the performance of a complex query, I simply manually create a view in the database, and manually create an EF object over it. It sounds like it would save you a lot of time. You can do this with Code-First if you tell the MigrationsConfig where to find the view - instruction here: http://laboremus.ug/?p=1708
... and you can also join the view to other objects.

Answer (score 4):

What happens if you try to do a more straight forward translation to LINQ?

```
var latestState = from s in _context.States
                  group s by s.ID_T into sg
                  select new { ID_T = sg.Key, Time = sg.Time.Max() };

var ans = from t in _context.T
          where t.FK == 1
          join sub in latestState on t.ID equals sub.ID_T into subj
          from sub in subj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          join s in _context.States on new { t.ID, sub.Time } equals new { s.ID, s.Time } into sj
          from s in sj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new { t.ID, t.Description, State = (s == null ? 0 : s.State) };
```

Apparently the `??` operator will translate to `COALESCE` and may handle an empty table properly, so you could replace the `select` with:

```
          select new { t.ID, t.Description, State = s.State ?? 0 };
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I have already tried very similar (almost identical) query. The result is even worse (it performs three queries and in one of them it selects everything from `States` ). The problem lies in the grouping, EF Core is not yet able to translate it to SQL and performs it on the client side. See my updated question and Smit's comment.

Comment: OK, my "almost identical" LINQ query was actually not almost identical. Yours is simpler and results in a simpler SQL query. There's only a small mistake in the second join condition (`s.ID` should be `s.ID_T` - see my answer). +1 for that even though it does not solve my original problem.

Comment: oh, and there should be `group s by s.ID_T`

Comment: Your LINQ example said `group x by x.id` so I copied that. I have modified both queries to use `ID_T`.